# Invalid shape (105, 126, 2) for image data

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to dipslay an image with plt.imshow(), but I'm always getting this error message : Invalid shape (105, 126, 2) for image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7AfL.png)data

Comment: Well your images should either be `(M, N)` or `(M, N, 3)`  or `(M, N, 4)` according to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html).

Comment: Well, do you think you *should* be able to produce an image from that data? If so, then *how should that work*? What does each dimension represent? If not - then I assume the question is really about why you have that data. In which case, we can't tell you why the data is the wrong shape unless you *show specifically the code that produces it*.

Comment: So I have a folder with images and I wanted to convert them to numpy arrays.

So this is the code I used:

`for filename in tqdm(glob.glob ('/content/drive/MyDrive/Pre-Processed-CuM-LW115/*'),desc='Loading'):

   img=Image.open(filename) 
   image_list.append(np.array(img))

np.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/CuM-LW115', np.array(image_list))`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to show an image with an array of RGB values, this won't work indeed. For every pixel it expects and R, G and B value, so expects a shape of (105, 126, 3). Hope this helps, feel free to correct if any mistakes